# Git Bash issue is coming when trying to execute in Rstudio

Tags: rstudio, git-bash

bash is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file is coming when trying to execute {bash} in R studio

I want it to smoothly run the {bash} command in Rstudio.
Also it is throwing error evry time  run it